# Lint custom rule for check method exceed in class

Tags: android, lint

I am using this sample code for custom lint implementation: 
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-custom-lint-rules

1. Now I want to implement rules for following conditions: Need to
   check no of line in class should not be exceed more than 250
   character.
2. Class method should not be exceed more than 20

How can we implement this?

Comment: You may need to write your own lint checker. Refer http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-custom-rules

Comment: @GokulNathKP I know but not working properly that's why i raised query here for solution.